# Add new column to Panda dataframe based on other column

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a new column to a Panda dataset.
This new column df['Year_Prod'] is derived from another one df['title'] from which I am extracting the year.

**Data example:**

```
country    designation     title
Italy      Vulkà Bianco    Nicosia 2013 Vulkà Bianco (Etna)         
Portugal   Avidagos        Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red (Douro)
```

**Code:**

```
import re

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'test.csv', index_col=0)

df['Year_Prod']=re.findall('\\d+', df['title'])

print(df.head(10))
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
 File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3119, in __setitem__self._set_item(key, value)

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3194, in _set_item value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3391, in _sanitize_column value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4001, in _sanitize_index raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')

**ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index**
```

Please let me know your thoughts on this, thanks.

Comment: Do any of your titles have more than one number in them?

Comment: @G.Anderson, good question, I previously checked and only have one appearance per title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pandas [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['Year_Prod']= df.title.str.extract('(\d{4})')

    country     designation     title                                          Year_Prod
0   Italy       Vulkà Bianco    Nicosia 2013 Vulkà Bianco (Etna)                2013
1   Portugal    Avidagos        Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red (Douro)   2011
```

Edit: As @Paul H. suggested in comments, the reason your code doesn't work is that re.findall expects a string but you are passing a series. It can be done using apply where at every row, the value passed is a string but doesn't make much sense as str.extract is more efficient.

```
df.title.apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d{4}', x)[0])
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining that `re.findall` expects a single string as its second arg, but the OP passed `pandas.Series` instead. Further, the OP should know that functions in the standard library in general will will not accept pandas objects

Answer (score 5):

`pandas` have `findall` as well

```
df.title.str.findall('\d+').str[0]
Out[239]: 
0    2013
1    2011
Name: title, dtype: object

#df['Year_Prod']= df.title.str.findall('\d+').str[0] from pygo
```

Comment: Excellent @W-B ,  added to my list :) +1, However, can you pls add that to the answer to complete the desired output so someone looking for this can benefit out of it  `df['Year_Prod']= df.title.str.findall('\d+').str[0]`

Comment: @pygo sure :-) added

Comment: @W-B, thnx Dude  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying a delimiter - the default is `,` for `.read_csv`

You can use `pd.Series.apply`:

```
import re    
import pandas as pd

def year_finder(x):
    return re.findall('\\d+', x)[0] # First match I find

df=pd.read_csv(r'test.csv', delimiter='||', index_col=0)
df['Year_Prod']= df["title"].apply(year_finder)

print(df.head(10))
```

edit: for `str.extract` method see @Vaishali's answer

Answer (score 1):

Just another way around based on `iloc` method.

```
>>> df['Year_Prod'] = df.iloc[:,2].str.extract('(\d{4})', expand=False)
>>> df
    country   designation                                          title Year_Prod
0     Italy  Vulkà Bianco               Nicosia 2013 Vulkà Bianco (Etna)      2013
1  Portugal      Avidagos  Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red (Douro)      2011
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `str.translate` instead of `regex`

```
def f(x):
  x = ''.join([c if c.isdigit() else ' ' for c in x])
  return x.strip().split(None, 1)[0]

df.assign(Year_Prod=df.title.map(f))

    country   designation                                          title Year_Prod
0     Italy  Vulkà Bianco               Nicosia 2013 Vulkà Bianco (Etna)      2013
1  Portugal      Avidagos  Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red (Douro)      2011
```